# Can't remote desktop into Windows 7 workstation in SBS 2003 network

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, netgear, windows-sbs-2003

We have a Windows Small Business Server 2003 network with Windows XP and 7 workstations. Some of the workstations have custom remote desktop ports and the modem/firewall (Netgear DG834) forwards these ports through to the workstation (static IP).

All of the workstations works fine except one new Windows 7 PC. I set the custom port in the registry to 3392, forwarded the port in the Netgear firewall, but when I attempt to RDP into it externally it just errors ("This computer cannot connect to the remote computer").

If I remote into this workstation on port 3392 from a computer within the local network it works fine.

I ran GRC Shields Up from the workstation and it reports that port 3392 is open.

I changed to another port and it made no difference.

I stopped the Windows 7 firewall service on the workstation and it didn't help.

The Netgear doesn't seem to have any logging for successful or failed connection attempts.

I can't figure out why this one computer won't work. Any ideas or advice on how I can test where the problem is?

Comment: can you can log into it internally when you are onsite from another pc on your internal domain?

Comment: whats the status of the win7 fw is it on and is it using a public profile that may be different then your domain profile.

Comment: @dasko: I can log into the workstation onsite, its only externally when i have the problem.

Comment: @tony roth: W7 Firewall is on in domain profile and off in other profiles, I also tried with the firewall service stopped to test but made no difference.

Comment: Can you run WireShark on the PC that is being remoted into to see if it is indeed receiving the request packets?

Comment: You should probably toss the home router and get some reliable network gear that actually does what you tell it to.